# Security when allowing user-entered aggregation pipeline in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, security

I need to allow system administrators to select (Meteor) app users for a mailshot. The administrators want to be able to select users by arbitrary properties of user groups. The users and groups are stored in a Mongo database. I have obvious concerns about allowing user-entered database commands.

I can provide a UI component for administrators to enter an aggregation pipeline as a text string. The server then does something like this:

```
if (pipeline.search('$out:') === -1) {
    const parsedPipeline = JSON.parse(pipeline);

    const result = Promise.await(Groups.aggregate(parsedPipeline).toArray()); // aggregate returns an aggregationCursor, and it is async
}
```

The server has already checked that the user is logged in and has administrative privileges.

Any pipeline that contains 'out' is rejected.

Is this enough security to ensure that an entered pipeline cannot write to the database? The administrators are entitled to view any data in the database so I think that's OK. But is there any way apart from 'out' that an aggregation pipeline can write to the database?

Thank you for any information.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than approaching it that way, why not set up a mongo user who only has `read` access to the database and use that to connect and run the aggregation commands? Trying to secure this with regular expressions seems fragile, and like something that might not be forwards compatible.

Comment: If you aren't already, I'd also recommend adding a `maxTimeMS` to any user-entered aggregation commands! Users are great at coming up with crazy queries that can bring a db to a halt

Comment: I haven't used it, but mongo compass is supposed to be a good tool for creating pipelines and exploring data. If you have mongo users set up with only the necessary permissions, it might be simpler to set up that tool for your admins rather than trying to recreate a subset of it. https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass (there's a community edition)

Comment: maxTimeMS is a good suggestion but I can't figure out how to use it with aggregation. I can't find an example in the docs. I've tried const options = {   maxTimeMS: 5, }; Projects.aggregate(parsedPipeline, options); but it is not working, any idea why?

Comment: I'm unsure about how mongoose handles things, but that looks correct to me. With the shell, it's `db.coll.aggregate([], {maxTimeMS: 1})`. Are you sure it's not working? 5ms is a decent amount of time. (I really want to figure out a good way of causing a slow aggregation to be able to test stuff like this out more easily, but I'm not sure if it's possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56447145/is-there-a-good-way-to-intentionally-cause-a-slow-mongo-aggregation-operation)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/ has docs about options

Comment: Thanks! FYI I'm not using mongoose, this is plain nodeJS. In the referenced docs about options, I do not see an example of how to set options? Just a description and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.  Even with 1 ms it's not timing out, is that likely with ~3000 users to search?

Comment: Pass it in as the second parameter (like you're doing). It's described by the definition (`db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, options)`). Assuming things are indexed, searching 3000 users should be decently quick. How about just doing it with an empty array so you return everything? That should be slow enough to check. You could also do `db.test_coll.explain({executionStats: true}).aggregate([], {maxTimeMS: 1});` and check `"executionTimeMillis"`

Comment: Thanks. I'm using https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate which may limit what functions I can access. I can pass in explain: true as an option but it doesn't display the executionStats, and db.test_coll.explain({executionStats: true}) gives me an error that explain is not a function.

Comment: I agree it would be better to disallow write in this operation, but I can't see a way to do this with Meteor. Read-only views don't seem to be supported, and the way collection publications work doesn't seem to support limited permissions. It's all down to me what operations to write on the server.

Comment: It might be worth opening up a different question about how to set up a read only user & connection for meteor.